# linux| firewall| windows: open a socket , test a port

Tags: linux, firewall, port

I have a Linux machine.

The network has a very restrictive firewall config.

I want to reach this machine from a Windows computer using port 4449.

How can I test if communication is working correctly?

- Open a socket and listen on port 4449. In Linux how? Using which utility?
- Test the connection from Windows: telnet, or something else?

Comment: What Linux distro do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

netcat is an utility that is included in many Linux distributions.

To listen on TCP port 4449 try

```
nc -v -l 4449
```

And on the client telnet should be perfect

Comment: this will do !!  Thanks !!! i had a huntch it was netcat , but didnt know how to do it ....

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean when you say "the network has very restristive firewall config"?
What firewall you're using? 
By iptables is done so:

```
iptables -A INPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4449 -j ACCEPT
```

To test:

```
telnet o xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 4449
```